# dojo 1.8 - naming and destroy instance of the object

Tags: dojo

Hi How to name and destroy instance of the object?
Please see [my working](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/sTxbh/14/) in jsfiddle

```
declare("obj_Button", [_WidgetBase], {
        buildRendering: function () {
            // create the DOM for this widget
            this.domNode = domConstruct.create("button", {
                innerHTML: "New Button Instance"
            });
        }
    });

    on(dom.byId('btn1'), "click", function(evt)
    {
        (new obj_Button()).placeAt(dom.byId('id'));
         //name the instance
    });

    parser.parse(); // check out more!

    on(dom.byId('btn2'), "click", function(evt)
    {
    // destroy the instance by name, not object
    });
```

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the ID of the widget, you can use "dijit/registry" to get the widget, then destroy it:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
   registry.byId("myWidgetId").destroyRecursive();
});
```

If you only know the ID of the dom node, you can registry.findWidgets() (if the widget is a child of the dom node) or registry.getEnclosingWidget() (if the dom node is a child of the widget).

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/registry.html#finding-all-widgets-underneath-a-dom-node

Comment: Hi Thanks for directing  me to the link. There's another way by forcing instance's id to be named, when creating  a new instance, that way, I can destroy the instance by its own id. You are right if I know id.. Thanks again

Comment: Hi How do I label every button with different texts each time the new button is created?